# How to upload file from android device using Automation on web based application

Tags: c#, android, selenium, automation, appium

I have a requirement to uplaod file from android file(eg .txt or .png ) to a web based application from android device.
Simple scenario like upload pic from android device to flipkart profile page or facebook page,Facing problem in selecting file from Gallery,Documents and other options on android from desktop I was able to do using UIA.

Comment: Have you tried by using `.sendKeys` ?

Comment: HI, After i click on the upload button on my web application(using selenium) from android phone I don't see any control to pass .sendKeys ,all I see is window pop with "choose an option" screen with options as camera and files,dont really know where exactly you want me to use .SendKeys

Comment: you don't have to click on the element, just use `.sendKeys("your//image//path");` instead of `.click();`